# yum install npm fails with failure: repodata/repomd.xml from pgdg10

Tags: yum, node.js, npm

I am trying to install the npm through yum install npm command but it fails every time with the below log:

```
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     | 6.0 kB     00:00     
google-chrome                                            | 1.3 kB     00:00     
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel--x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#77 - "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (PostgreSQL 10  - x86_64),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=pgdg10 ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable pgdg10
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=pgdg10

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=pgdg10.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from pgdg10: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel--x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#77 - "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"
```

I already tried executing the below steps but nothing worked. I am not using the proxy and my RHEL version is 7.6 with a valid subscription.

```
# yum clean all
# rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
# yum repolist
```

And I checked that I am correctly subscribed to by the command:

```
#subscription-manager release --show
Release 7.6
```

Answer (score 1):

In the /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory there were two repos pgdg-12-repo.d and pgdg-10-repo.d. I am not using these repos anymore. And deleted these two repos and then executed following commands. It worked.

```
#yum clean metadata
#yum update
#yum install -y gcc-c++ make
#yum install nodejs
```